# Switch statement - variable "case"?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

For `ScoreOption`, I expect to get the following input "A", "B", and T_(state) for example T_NY

How can I write a case switch statement for the third option T_(state)?

```
switch(ScoreOption.ToUpper().Trim())
{
    case "A":
        ....
        break;
    case "B":
        ....
        break;
    case T_????
        ....
        break;
}
```

I might as well write if-else statement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string s = ScoreOption.ToUpper().Trim();
switch(s)
{
    case "A":

        ....

        break;
    case "B":

        ....

        break;
    default:
        if (s.StartsWith("T_"))
        {
        ....
        }                       
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't have a variable as a case in a switch statement.  You'll have to do something like

```
case "T_NY":
case "T_OH":
break;
```

etc.

Now what you could do is

```
switch (ScoreOption.ToUpper().Trim())
{
   case "A":
    break;
   case "B":
    break;
   default: 
//catch all the T_ items here. provided that you have specifed all other 
//scenarios above the default option.
    break;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    switch(ScoreOption.ToUpper().Substring(0, 1)) 
    { 
        case "A": 

            .... 

            break; 
        case "B": 

            .... 

            break; 
        case "T":
            ValidateState(ScoreOption);
            .... 
            break; 

    }
```

But, yeah, a series of if statements might be better. That's all the switch is going to generate anyway, since the system can't do any fancy jump table tricks on strings.

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a dictionary with functions containing the code to run when the value matches.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Action<T,U,V>();
dict.Add("A", (x,y,z) => { 
  ...
});
var func = dict[val];
func(v1,v2,v3);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about handling A and B separately and the switch being the decision on State which is the biggest variable. Something like;

```
char firstCharacter = ScoreOption.ToUpper().CharAt(0);

if(firstCharacter.Equals("A")) {
  ...
}else if(firstCharacter.Equals("B")) {
  ...
}else {
  switch(ScoreOption.Split("_")[1]) {
    case "NY":
      ...
      break;
    case "OH":
      ...
      break;
    default:
      ...
      break;
  }
}
```